# Start-Process fails with msbuild with write-error in powershell

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I try do something very simple like this but it fails with exception:

```
Build-VisualStudioSolution <<<<   
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Build-VisualStudioSolution
```

simple script is  like that.
When I run the same from command line it is fine.

```
@buildArgs = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe C:\WORK\test\test.sln /t:build"

try{
Start-Process @BuildArgs 

}
catch{            
Write-Error ($_.Message);            
}
```

thanks for tips

Answer (score 1):

First thing, you don't need to catch if you just want to print the error.

Second, your syntax is wrong.  It should look like this:

```
$buildArgs = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe", C:\WORK\test\test.sln", "/t:build"

Start-Process @BuildArgs
```